# joining data.frames from within two lists based on regular expression

Tags: r

This is what my workspace looks like:

```
list.u = list(list.1 = replicate(n = 10,
                     expr = {data.frame(Var1 = as.factor(paste0("X", c(1:10))), 
                                        Var2 = as.factor(paste0("X", c(11:20))), 
                                        value=rnorm(10))},
                     simplify = F),
            list.2 = replicate(n = 10,
                      expr = {data.frame(Var1 = as.factor(paste0("X", c(1:10))), 
                                         Var2 = as.factor(paste0("X", c(11:20))), 
                                         value=rnorm(10))},
                      simplify = F))

list2env(list.u , .GlobalEnv )

names(list.1) <- paste0(LETTERS[1:10],"_NTI")
names(list.2) <- sample(paste0(LETTERS[1:10],"_RC")) # not the same order

###if meaningful can again be possibly converted to 
###list.u <- list(list.1, list.2)
```

What i want to achieve is the joining of two correspondent data.frames based on the string found bevore _NTI and _RC, respectively:

```
library(dplyr)
df.A <- list.1$A_NTI %>% right_join(list.2$A_RC, by=c("Var1","Var2"))
df.B <- list.1$B_NTI %>% right_join(list.2$B_RC, by=c("Var1","Var2"))
df.C <- list.1$C_NTI %>% right_join(list.2$C_RC, by=c("Var1","Var2"))
```

and so on for every pair of matching elements of list.1 and list.2

How can i do this`?

Comment: This is straightforward if the lists are in the same order like this. Do you need to account for different orders, or missing elements in the lists?

Comment: different orders, unfortunately. It should however be possible to order the data.frames in each list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first match the names using a simple regex, rearrange the data frames in the list, and merge one by one, i.e.

```
list.1 <- list.1[names(list.1)[match(sub('_.*', '', names(list.1)), sub('_.*', '', names(list.2)))]]
Map(function(i, j)merge(i, j, by = c('Var1', 'Var2'), all.y = TRUE), list.1, list.2)
```

which gives,

> ```
> $A_NTI
>    Var1 Var2      value.x    value.y
> 1    X1  X11  1.111072143  0.9893348
> 2   X10  X20  0.205016698 -1.0370611
> 3    X2  X12 -1.153484350 -0.1581219
> 4    X3  X13 -0.136188465 -0.8258913
> 5    X4  X14  0.845438616  1.0676754
> 6    X5  X15 -0.090040790 -0.6626899
> 7    X6  X16 -0.003032729  0.4220376
> 8    X7  X17  0.132374562 -0.5993826
> 9    X8  X18 -0.049654084  0.1161918
> 10   X9  X19  0.408352891 -0.4193510
>
> $B_NTI
>    Var1 Var2     value.x    value.y
> 1    X1  X11 -1.54096443  1.6954890
> 2   X10  X20  0.08418433 -1.1082467
> 3    X2  X12  0.77535586  0.9035127
> 4    X3  X13 -1.82040060  0.1870822
> 5    X4  X14 -1.00129026 -1.6371800
> 6    X5  X15  0.32455294  0.4544704
> 7    X6  X16  0.25704291 -0.1451332
> 8    X7  X17  0.61232730  2.1936744
> 9    X8  X18  0.43594609 -2.3836932
> 10   X9  X19 -0.23466536  1.3418739
>
> $C_NTI
>    Var1 Var2     value.x     value.y
> 1    X1  X11 -0.02400835  0.03265689
> 2   X10  X20 -1.78936480  1.55964999
> ....
>
> ...
> ```

**NOTE:** The `merge(..., all.y = TRUE)` is the base R equivalent of `dplyr::right_join`

Answer (score 2):

```
stopifnot(length(list.1) == length(list.2))
stopifnot(length(setdiff(substr(names(list.1), 1, 1), substr(names(list.2), 1, 1))) == 0)
```

Looks like it'll do here to just order each list alphabetical before merging.

```
Map(merge, list.1[order(names(list.1))], list.2[order(names(list.2))], all.y=TRUE)
```